# Communicating with WCF Service without Metadata

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a 3rd party WCF service I am trying to communicate with. I can't get it's WSDL, or connect it using the service reference.

I have used Fiddler to monitor and emulate traffic, and that has worked, but I am unsure how to decode the application/msbin1 format into a useable format (I expect it should be XML by the end of decoding). I have installed the WCF Binary plugin. The raw text is (shortened and censored):

```
@getAllEntriesResponsehttp://tempuri.org/@getAllEntriesResult   a
DomainServices  i)http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance^TotalCount  ^
RootResults b6http://schemas.datacontract.org/...
```

Meanwhile the WCF Binary looks like (xml tree):

```
getAllEntriesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
-- getAllEntriesResult xmlns:a="DomainServices" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
---- a:TotalCount
...
```

The code I have written for emulating this so far is:

```
        IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1",8888);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("<url>.sc/binary/getAllEntries?elementID=0");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/msbin1";
        request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        request.Proxy = proxy;
        //request.GetRequestStream().Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        byte[] b = new byte[response.ContentLength];
        response.GetResponseStream().Read(b, 0, b.Length);

        XmlReader binaryreader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(b, 0, b.Length, dictionary,  XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(binaryreader);
        return xdoc;
```

I do get back the same thing that Fiddler gets so my REQUEST is working as intended (as far as I know). What I think is going wrong is that the bytes (b) are are in the format I mentioned earlier, and so when it's passed to the XML it errors (it doesn't look like XML to me anyway, I'm not sure if it can read this 'binary xml').

The exception I get is 'The input source is not correctly formatted' at xdoc.Load(binaryreader) with the stack trace:

```
at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.ReadValue(XmlBinaryNodeType nodeType, ValueHandle value)
at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadNode()
at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
...
```

NOTE: dictionary is populated with 485 entries which are (as I understand it) shorthand lists of re-occurring strings which are known, and used to reduce transfer sizes. A sample of my list is:

```
                dictionary.Add("mustUnderstand");
                dictionary.Add("Envelope");
                dictionary.Add("http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
                dictionary.Add("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
                dictionary.Add("Header");
                dictionary.Add("Action");
                dictionary.Add("To");
                dictionary.Add("Body");
                ...
                dictionary.Add("Detail");
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing at this point. I'm sure it's something small but I'm not familiar enough with this stuff to get it to work properly.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you get the WSDL?  Is the 3rd party unwilling to give it to?  It sounds like metadata publishing may be disabled, but in that case they should provide you a WSDL.

Comment: A fair question. I haven't asked for the WSDL. When I query the service with ?WSDL it won't provide it automatically. This is a service I am a user for, I am trying to build a better UI for it.

Comment: If metadata publishing is disabled (and it sounds like it is), then querying the service with `?WSDL` won't get you anything.  I'd contact the owner of the service and ask for the WSDL.  It'll save you a lot of time and headaches :)

Comment: I will see about doing that. I understand that if the service is disabled, its likely they don't want people doing it. And that raises concerns for people providing help online. Part of my interest is as a hobby, I recently did something similar to learn JSON. Despite whether I get the WDSL or not, I am still interested in how it all works under the hood, and what this format is (from what I gather its binary XML but I can't find much about it).

Answer (score 0):

After some review, I realized some of the XML was being parsed, but not all of it. When I read it one element at a time, I realized it was breaking at a specific point. I then checked my byte array and sure enough, my byte array was incomplete. Comparing the Stream.Read count with the expected amount, I discovered I wasn't getting the full byte array.

Replacing my Stream reader for the response with:

```
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
        byte[] b = ms.ToArray();
```

Gave me the full thing. It now parses into an XMLDocument correctly.